# Are there fluid tripod heads made for panning with a lightweight, compact camera?

Tags: tripod-heads, panning

Are there fluid tripod heads made for use with compact or at least lightweight cameras (such as my LX100)? Most seem built to support a tank (or full-blown DSLR/video camera).

I would like to be able to pan with my small compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have specifically asked for a Fluid Head - presumably for video work - I Just bought a Manfrotto MVH500AH
(https://www.manfrotto.com/global/500-fluid-video-head-with-flat-base-mvh500ah/)

This is a fairly lightweight head which I have used for everything between a Sony NEX5 and a Nikon D800, even a Black Magic Ursa.

Very smooth, adjustable drag, lockable etc.

BUT you will need a suitably sturdy tripod, a cheapo twisty bendy thing just wont cut it.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. This looks like it fits the bill -- do you know of any even lighter alternatives?

Comment: Interested in the same, looking for something lightweigt and small, for use with compact devices such as LX100, smartphone, gopro. Products I found are overkill, my "budget" is around 500g max. My purpose is for 360 photo rather than video though.

Comment: @shiouming - why do you need a fluid head if smooth panning isnt necessary?

Comment: Well, not a must to be fluid head in my case, I'm open to other product too, as long as size and weight work out. I plan to take 360 photo on a long trip for backpacking and hiking.

Comment: ok, then id suggest one of the lightweight Manfrotto tripods

Comment: To keep size as small as possible, I'm also exploring to combine GoPro-like tiltable mount + small panning head. Today I finally found one such mount that supports camera and "appears" reliable, but panning heads I found are all motorised and larger/heavier than necessary, mostly marketed for time-lapsed video.

Answer (score 1):

A video camera tripod is different than a still photograph tripod, because it needs some resistance when panning and tilting.

It is normally more sturdy because it is expected to stay in place while you move the head. A light one will move when you pan. It does not really matter if the camera is light or heavy.

Of course if the camera is heavier you need one more reliable, in materials and construction.

If you just need a tripod for still photography, just buy one you like. But feel it first, do not buy something "cheap" just because.

Comment: thank you for advice. I am looking for a head that will allow me to pan while shooting video with my LX100.